# Marketing Cloud RMM not honoring direct forwards

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

we have been using SFMC for more than a year, utilizing Dynamic Sender Profiles. The RMM feature on the dynamic profile is set to use direct forwards, as we want recipients to engage in direct conversation with our consultants afterwards. However, we stumbled upon some cases, where, the email was correctly send from the respective sender (the consultants personal email address), but the reply of the customer went to the **Routing Address for Remaining Replies**.

Any ideas why this might me happening?

Just to note that it happened on some emails sends, not all (e.g. same journey, same template, but some customer replies were sent directly, as expected, some were routed)

Thanks,

Emil

Comment: look at the reply links and determine what information they contain. e.g. there is a reference to SubscriberID (not key), which could get invalidated because of contact deletions, as the SubscriberID might no longer be found in the system. This is a guess but I've seen this happen in a system where we periodically removed "one off sendout" contacts older than a few weeks or months.

Comment: and I'll add for clarity: if the subscriberId cannot be found, a fallback would be used because the routing address cannot be determined (which would lead into "remaining replies")

Comment: Thanks, Jonas, I think there is no contact deletion, but it is worth checking.